# Error installing Photoshop CS 6 on my Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, wine, virtualization, 32-bit, photoshop

When I try to install Photoshop CS 6 on my Ubuntu 17.04, I get the following error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

> Error in POL_Wine
>   Starting 64-bit process Photoshop.exe is not supported in 32-bit virtual drives

Answer (score 3):

In the PlayOnLinux install menu, choose *Install a non-listed program* in the lower left corner:

[image: PlayOnLinux install menu]

Follow the installation steps and create a 64-bit virtual drive on the way:

[image: PlayOnLinux Wizard – kind of virtual drive]

Then choose your installation (probably `.exe`) file of Adobe Photoshop:

[image: PlayOnLinux Wizard – browse]

Comment: If it answers your question please accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

The wine version installed is 32 bits, which will not support 64 bits process of photoshop.exe. You have to install wine.i686 . Refer this article https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8813-1.html